# Unit Testing of Remote API calls, How it works with JSON Objects

Tags: json, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, controller, nunit

In my web api, I have a method that call a service that return a deserialized  JSON object. I can't find a way for unit testing that is working for me.
the following is the code from the controller:

```
     [RequireHttps]
     [Route("api/GetItem/{id}")]
     public class GetItemController : ControllerBase
    {
     private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     private Item item = new Item();

     [RequireHttps]
     [Route("api/GetItem/{id}")]
     public Item GetItem(string name, string password)
     {
        string url = "https://localhost:5001/";


       string uri = url + "api/item/" + name+ "/" +  password "/"  ;
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
       MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
       HttpResponseMessage Res = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;              

            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                var MemResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                member = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item> 
                (MemResponse);

            }

            return Ok(item);
        }
    }
```

The unit test I wrote suppose to check the wrong user name and password, but when running the test it just gray out and never runs

```
  [TestMethod]
   public void GetItemWithWrongPassword()
   {      
    var username = "Hellow";
    var pass = "There";
    var controller = new GetItemController();
    var response = controller.GetItem(username, pass);
    var s = response.ToString();
    Assert.AreEqual(s, "System.Web.Http.Results.NotFoundResult");
}
```

what I'm doing wrong?
Later on I want to test if the connection to the remote API.

Comment: Test controller is tightly coupled to implementation concerns that make testing it in isolation difficult. You are also using http client wrong. Decouple the HttpClient and order to make controller flexible to be tested in isolation. The test is also not awaiting an async call so it wont actually know what is happening with that test as it is being executed in another thread

Comment: what do you mean by using the http client wrong? This is my first time working with web api, so I'm not sure I fully understand what I'm doing

Comment: Reference [You're using HttpClient wrong](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: Just also realised you are mixing blocking calls like `.Result` with async calls that can lead to deadlocks

Comment: I'm not sure I got that one

Comment: `var MemResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` will cause dealock because it is being called within GetItem, an async function.  Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: @Nkosi I thank you for your advice. I now updated the method code in the controller  as you may see accordingly. however my test still graying out

Answer (score 0):

Creating an instance of `GetItemController` and calling its methods is not a good idea, because the whole message pipeline is skipped in the process.

I see two options here:

1. Put the code (including the `HttpClient`) that is contained in `GetItem` into another class and call the method on an instance of that class, e.g.:

   ```
   public class ItemClient
   {
       private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();            

       public Item GetItem(string name, string password)
       {
           Item item = null;
           string url = "https://localhost:5001/";
           string uri = url + "api/item/" + name + "/" + password;
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
           HttpResponseMessage Res = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;              

           if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
               var MemResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
               item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(MemResponse);
           }
           return item;
       }
   }
   ```

   Controller method:

   ```
   [RequireHttps]
   [Route("api/GetItem/{name}/{password}")]
   public Item GetItem(string name, string password)
   {
       ItemClient client = new ItemClient();
       var item = client.GetItem(name, password);
       return Ok(item);
   }
   ```

   Test method:

   ```
   [TestMethod]
   public void GetItemWithWrongPassword()
   {      
       var username = "Hellow";
       var password = "There";
       ItemClient client = new ItemClient();
       var item = client.GetItem(username, password);
       Assert.IsNull(item);
   }
   ```
2. Call the controller method using a HttpClient in the test method:

   ```
   [TestMethod]
   public void GetItemWithWrongPassword()
   {      
       var username = "Hellow";
       var password = "There";

       string url = "https://localhost/"; // Host of your Web API

       string uri = url + "api/GetItemController/GetItem/" + username + "/" + password;
       HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
       HttpResponseMessage Res = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;              
       var s = Res.ToString();
       Assert.AreEqual(s, "System.Web.Http.Results.NotFoundResult");
   }
   ```

I personally prefer option 1 due to two benefits:

1. Debugging the test is easier. Debugging a call by `HttpClient` (option 2)
   usually means that you have to start a second instance of Visual
   Studio and set a breakpoint there.
2. The code can be used in other projects that are not Web API services. The endpoints become simple wrappers around the actual business logic.